# Filter XML fields with JOOX

Tags: java, xml, parsing, filter, joox

I need to filter many XML files like this:

```
<header>
   <type>1</type>
   <time>today</time>
</header>
<message>
   <Event...>
      <Counter...>
   ...
</message>
```

I need to pick only all the message content whose header.type == 1. I'm reading from multiple files I need to select the message content with type == 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just little updated your XML-structure to be well-formed. Here are several XML files for testing:

```
========= one.xml ==========
<root>
   <header>
      <type>1</type>
   </header>
   <message>right</message>
</root>

========= two.xml ==========
<root>
   <header>
      <type>1</type>
   </header>
   <message>right</message>
</root>

========= three.xml ==========
<root>
   <header>
      <type>2</type>
   </header>
   <message>wrong</message>
</root>
```

And simple code looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;

import static org.joox.JOOX.$;

public class JooxDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final File dirWithXmls = new File("xmls");

        for (File xmlFile : dirWithXmls.listFiles()) {

            final String message = $(xmlFile).xpath("//header[type='1']/../message").text();

            System.out.println(xmlFile.getName() + ", message: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
one.xml, message: right
three.xml, message: null
two.xml, message: right
```

As you can see **message** has been fetched only in case if **header** is of **type** **1**.

Therefore you can delete `.text()` and do what you need with **message** node after simple not-null check.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You have helped me a lot!!